# Can I change Info bar colour on scene change

Tags: python, interface, scene

I am trying to write a script to set Interface colours for individual scenes. When I switch scenes in the Info bar drop down menu I want to change the Info Bar background colour. This gives better feedback for scene swapping/tracking.
So far I've got `bpy.context.user_preferences.themes[0].info.space.header = (1,0,0)`

- I guess I need to create an open list of scenes that I can append later.
- Then allocate the spectrum of colours to it?
- Not sure I can create a UI to allocate colours to scenes, so I'll have to bump the values in increments instead.

But first I'm stuck on calling the colour change (I considered iterating a bunch of themes and switching them as needed). At the BA forum it was suggested that the scene change is a frame change event but I'm not sure how to separate that from any other frame changes...

Hopefully if I can set up colours for the info bar I could tie them to node scene inputs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cool idea, I wrote this addon for me just now and I triggered the Header draw event. You can copy it from below or from here: [scene_colored_header.py](https://pasteall.org/dG5Y)

EDIT: Updated to the newer Version. Don't use the old version, it generates a continuous redraw of the Header, wich I don' noticed. leads to cpu inceasement

blender 2.8 and above:

```
bl_info = {
           "name": "Colored Header for each scene",
           "author": "Leon95, Idea: 3pointedit",
           "version": (1, 2),
           "blender": (3, 0, 0),
           "location": "Properties > Scene Tab > Scene Panel > Display Color",
           "description": "Define a Header Color for every scene and display it in the Header",
           "category": "Scene"
           }

import bpy

def_color = bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(size = 4,min = 0.0,max = 1.0,
    default=list(bpy.context.preferences.themes[0].topbar.space.header))
def_color = list(bpy.context.preferences.themes[0].topbar.space.header)



def ui_properties_costum_header_color(self, context):
    row = self.layout.row()
    row.prop(context.scene, "headerColor")

def ui_info_header_refresh(self, context):
    #assign the property to the header theme every time it is redrawn
    l_co=context.window_manager.lastHeaderColor
    ch = context.preferences.themes[0].topbar.space.header
    cs = context.scene.headerColor
    #check, if reassignment is needed, since  assigning a color leads to redraw
    #(which the causes some kind of stack overflow)
    if not (round(l_co[0],3) == round(cs[0],3) and round(l_co[1],3) == round(cs[1],3) and round(l_co[2],3) == round(cs[2],3)):
        bpy.context.preferences.themes[0].topbar.space.header = bpy.context.scene.headerColor
    context.window_manager.lastHeaderColor=[cs[0],cs[1],cs[2]]


def register():
    co = list(bpy.context.preferences.themes[0].topbar.space.header)
    bpy.types.WindowManager.lastHeaderColor=bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(size = 3,min = 0.0,max = 1.0)
    bpy.types.Scene.headerColor = bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(
                                     name = "Display Color",
                                     subtype = "COLOR",
                                     size = 4,
                                     min = 0.0,
                                     max = 1.0,
                                     update = ui_info_header_refresh,
                                     default = co)

    bpy.types.SCENE_PT_scene.append(ui_properties_costum_header_color)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_HT_upper_bar.append(ui_info_header_refresh)
    #bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(ui_info_header_refresh)

    #reassigment forces redraw
    bpy.context.preferences.themes[0].topbar.space.header = bpy.context.preferences.themes[0].topbar.space.header

def unregister():
    bpy.types.SCENE_PT_scene.remove(ui_properties_costum_header_color)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_HT_upper_bar.remove(ui_info_header_refresh)
    #bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.remove(ui_info_header_refresh)
    bpy.context.preferences.themes[0].topbar.space.header = [def_color[0],def_color[1],def_color[2],def_color[3]]
    bpy.context.window_manager.lastHeaderColor=[0,0,0]
    del bpy.types.WindowManager.lastHeaderColor


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

blender 2.7 and below:

```
    #scene_colored_header.py
bl_info = {
           "name": "Colored Header for each scene",
           "author": "Leon95, Idea: 3pointedit",
           "version": (1, 1),
           "blender": (2, 68, 0),
           "location": "Properties > Scene Tab > Scene Panel > Display Color",
           "description": "Define a Header Color for every scene and display it in the Header",
           "category": "Scene"
           }
 
import bpy
 
def_color = bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(size = 3,min = 0.0,max = 1.0,
    default=bpy.context.user_preferences.themes[0].info.space.header.copy())
def_color = bpy.context.user_preferences.themes[0].info.space.header.copy()
 
 
 
def ui_properties_costum_header_color(self, context):
    row = self.layout.row()
    row.prop(context.scene, "headerColor")
 
def ui_info_header_refresh(self, context):
    #assign the property to the header theme every time it is redrawn
    l_co=context.window_manager.lastHeaderColor
    ch = context.user_preferences.themes[0].info.space.header
    cs = context.scene.headerColor
    #check, if reassignment is needed, since  assigning a color leads to redraw
    #(which the causes some kind of stack overflow)
    if not (round(l_co[0],3) == round(cs[0],3) and round(l_co[1],3) == round(cs[1],3) and round(l_co[2],3) == round(cs[2],3)):
        bpy.context.user_preferences.themes[0].info.space.header = bpy.context.scene.headerColor
    context.window_manager.lastHeaderColor=[cs[0],cs[1],cs[2]]
   
 
def register():
    co = bpy.context.user_preferences.themes[0].info.space.header.copy()
    bpy.types.WindowManager.lastHeaderColor=bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(size = 3,min = 0.0,max = 1.0)
    bpy.types.Scene.headerColor = bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(
                                     name = "Display Color",
                                     subtype = "COLOR",
                                     size = 3,
                                     min = 0.0,
                                     max = 1.0,
                                     update = ui_info_header_refresh,
                                     default = co)
 
    bpy.types.SCENE_PT_scene.append(ui_properties_costum_header_color)
    bpy.types.INFO_HT_header.append(ui_info_header_refresh)
    #bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(ui_info_header_refresh)
   
    #reassigment forces redraw
    bpy.context.user_preferences.themes[0].info.space.header = bpy.context.user_preferences.themes[0].info.space.header
 
def unregister():
    bpy.types.SCENE_PT_scene.remove(ui_properties_costum_header_color)
    bpy.types.INFO_HT_header.remove(ui_info_header_refresh)
    #bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.remove(ui_info_header_refresh)
    bpy.context.user_preferences.themes[0].info.space.header = [def_color[0],def_color[1],def_color[2]]
    bpy.context.window_manager.lastHeaderColor=[0,0,0]
    del bpy.types.WindowManager.lastHeaderColor
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: The coolest thing is that you can animate the header color :)

Comment: +1 This is pretty sweet. A cool idea from op indeed, registered and currently using it. Only critique is by default the color changes are rather subtle.

Comment: That is AWESOME, thanks sooo much! At least now I have a script to learn from, win win.

Comment: @3pointedit  :: I am new.  Do you know happen to know where I can assign the custom color?  Which variable is it?  Thank.

Comment: @cppBeginner script was no longer working since 2.8. It is now updateted and you can find the setting now in the scene tab of the properties window